# Kendo Grid: Select All Checkbox in Header Stops Working After .read()

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

I have two Kendo Grids that display after specific search filters are used.  The end-user has the ability to adjust the search filters and reload the datasource.  I allow this by checking if the grid exists, and if it already does - performing a grid.read() action (instead of reloading the entire grid).

This check and load works as expected.  The ability to select each individual row by clicking on the row, or select multiple rows by select the checkboxes (or using the click/drag method) works correctly (before and after the read()).  However, the select all checkbox (located in the header) stops functioning correctly after the read().

I have edited and added the code into fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a6Lbq1k7/12/), I apologize that it's not runnable (I was not able to remove enough of the datasource information to get just the grid to appear).

The select all checkbox works on the initial loading of the grid.  I tried to add the .change event ALSO to the else statement that calls the read(), thinking maybe it wasn't capturing the change event - but that didn't help.

```
$('#selectAllCheckbox').change(function () {
            onSelectAll();
        })
```

After the read(), when the select all checkbox is click - the box itself doesn't show a checkmark - and the multiple rows on the table are not selected.

```
function onSelectAll() {
var checked = ($('#selectAllCheckbox')[0].checked)
$('.checkbox').each(function (idx, item) {
    if (checked) {
        if (!($(item).closest('tr').is('.k-state-selected'))) {
            $(item).click();
        }
    } else {
        if ($(item).closest('tr').is('.k-state-selected')) {
            $(item).click();

        }
    }
});
setIsChecked();
};
```

Edit:

I was able to better replicate my issue starting with Kendo's demo, and then adding in each section of my code until it broke.  I was able to determine that the issue happens when attempting to combine the select all header checkbox feature with the multi-select feature (which has a dataBound event)  I need both of these features to work together.

See the example [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/ILETUWEZ):

Notice the header checkbox works correctly, until a feature of the grid is enabled (such as column sort), then it will stop "checking".  It will work every other time the feature is clicked.

It's as though the ability to "check" the header checkbox is being turned on and off.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $('#selectAllCheckbox').on('click',function(){ 
     
        if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
           $('.checkbox').prop('checked',true);
        }else {
           $('.checkbox').prop('checked',false);
        }
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="selectAllCheckbox"> check all
<hr>
<ol>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"> checkbox [1]<label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"> checkbox [2]<label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"> checkbox [3]<label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"> checkbox [4]<label></li>
</ol>
```